# Object rotation using keys

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glfw, glm-math

I want to rotate a cube using keys. This is a part of the code. When I press LEFT key, cube rotates to left, etc. My goal is to rotate cube all around, so I have to rotate it by `x` and `y` axis which causes a problem.

I have defined `mat4 rotation;` and used it to assign a rotation when I press and hold a key. When I hold the key, it is rotating, for example to left. Then I release the key and the object gets back to initial position (camera gets back to initial position, since object is not moving). I think this problem is causing the `auto rotateMat = rotation;` line which is defined below the key functions. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
    mat4 rotation; //global 

    if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_LEFT]){
                timer -= delta;
                rotation = rotate(mat4{}, timer * 0.5f, {0, 1, 0});
    }

    if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_RIGHT]){
                timer += delta;
                rotation = rotate(mat4{}, timer * 0.5f, {0, 1, 0});
    }

   if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_UP]){
                timer += delta;
                rotation = rotate(mat4{}, timer * 0.5f, {1, 0, 0});
   }

   if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_DOWN]){
                timer -= delta;
                rotation = rotate(mat4{}, timer * 0.5f, {1, 0, 0});
   }

   ...
   program.setUniform("ModelMatrix", rotation* cubeMat); 
   cube.render();
```

**UPDATE:**

So the problem to this was solved when I used matrix variable as global variable, not local.

Comment: If no key is pressed, then rotation will be a unity matrix. So yes, overriding rotateMat with a unity matrix is causing your cube to go back to it's initial position.

Comment: @BDL so how could I not override `rotateMat`? I thought when I assign `rotation` to `rotateMat` it will remember last position.

Comment: You could, for example, calculate a relative rotation in the ifs and multiply it to your current matrix.

Comment: The problem is still the same as in the initial question: You simply can't just have one global matrix and override it in each frame. Either you accumulate these rotations by multiplying relative rotations or you store both angles.

Comment: Please lets discuss it in the new question I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways how such an interaction can be implemented. One of the easier ones is to create a relative translation in every frame instead of a global one and add it to the current rotation:

For this, one has to store the sum of all rotations in a global varialbe

```
//Global variable
mat4 total_rotate;
```

And calculate the relative translation in every frame:

```
//In the function
mat4 rotation;

if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_LEFT]){
            rotation = rotate(mat4{}, delta, {0, 1, 0});
}

if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_RIGHT]){
            rotation = rotate(mat4{}, -delta, {0, 1, 0});
}

if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_UP]){
             rotation = rotate(mat4{}, delta, {1, 0, 0});
}

if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_DOWN]){
             rotation = rotate(mat4{}, -delta, {1, 0, 0});
}

total_rotate = total_rotate * rotation;
...
program.setUniform("ModelMatrix", total_rotate * cubeMat); 
cube.render();
```

As an alternative, you could store the two rotation angles instead and calculate the matrix in every frame:

```
//Global variables
float rot_x = 0.0f, rot_y = 0.0f;

//In every frame    
if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_LEFT]){
            rot_x += delta;
}

if(keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_RIGHT]){
            rot_x -= delta;
}

//Same for y

auto rotation = rotate(rotate(mat4{}, rot_y, {0, 1, 0}), rot_x, {1, 0, 0}
...
program.setUniform("ModelMatrix", rotation * cubeMat); 
cube.render();
```

Comment: The first solution does not work for me. It gets back to initial position.

Comment: Did you declare `total_rotate` as a global variable? Unless you override or reset total_rotate somewhere it shouldn't go back.

Comment: It is in function `onIdle() override ` but it should not reset in it. And for the second solution, it wants to rotate, but it does not, something is blocking movement. So it is only "shaking" on initial position when I press key to move.

Comment: You mean they are local variables in `onIdle`? Then all variables are reset whenever the function is executed. Please declare them in a way that they are **not** local to any function but global.

Comment: Never mind, it is working now, I did not notice it is still not global and I placed it on very top of the file. But as for the second solution, do you see a problem why its "stuck"?

Comment: You should have really told in the initial question that you are inside a class... Before I go on with randomly guessing around how your code might look like: Update your questions with all the relevant code. How are your methods called from the renderloop? From `public:` it sounds like you're using classes, then show what you have.

Comment: I have edited my comment above yours. Btw, since its working now, there is still a little problem, because it is rotating very fast now. The rotation is based on timestamp but it was rotating just fine before. Now it is very fast, the longer I hold button pressed, the faster it rotates (spins).

Comment: I believe the problem with fast rotation lays on the multiplication line `total_rotate *= rotation;` but no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Now that sounds as if you would also have declared `rotation` as a global variable... Everything from the second code block should be executed inside whatever function you have. Including the variable declaration.

Comment: I have not tried your last updated solution 1 since you have changed the variable for rotating based on time, but I have simply edited my original version of code as you can see in my original question. I have set `mat4 rotation` as global and removed assignment below key functions and now it works BUT, there is a glitch. LEFT RIGHT rotation works perfect, so does UP and DOWN, but when I do LEFT and UP/DOWN, or any other combination of x and y axis rotation, it starts always from front face of the object.

Comment: I have updated my question and also provided a video describing the problem.

Comment: btw are you sure the second code you provided is correct? For example that nested rotation? Because as I said earlier, it is stuck on initial position.

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. I have it implemented and working here (both versions). If it snaps back, then you somewhere reset rot_x or rot_y to 0. Debug your program and find out where that happens.

Comment: Okay, I have edited some variables also variables which control speed and I got it to work, except the rotation point is front face of the cube, not the middle of the cube. This is causing wrong rotations when the face is not aiming to the camera.